# В чем отличие дампа и бекапа БД?

Tags: база-данных

Прошу объяснить разницу между бекапом базы данных и ее дампом. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Все, уже разобрался http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30545/difference-between-database-dump-export-and-database-backup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из википедии

Дамп базы данных — файл с содержимым базы данных, позволяющий воссоздать базу данных «с нуля»; создается при помощи дампера.

т.е. Если вы выгрузили базу в файл с помощью возможности вашей штатной [СУБД](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%A3%D0%91%D0%94) - это файл для бекапа(backup), а если с помощью какой то внешней программы имеющую категорию дампер - это дамп.

и то и другое способ страховки от изменений или удаления БД с целью восстановления данных.